# select data into a gridview with a oracle procedure in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created this procedure. I want to select data into a gridview in c# using the parameters. Any help is highly appreciated

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_patient(
   p_fname PATIENT.FNAME%TYPE := NULL,
   p_sname PATIENT.SNAME%TYPE := NULL,
   p_dob PATIENT.DOB%TYPE := NULL,
   p_gender PATIENT.GENDER%TYPE := NULL) IS

CURSOR c_patient_cursor (p_fname PATIENT.FNAME%TYPE,  p_sname PATIENT.SNAME%TYPE, p_dob PATIENT.DOB%TYPE, p_gender PATIENT.GENDER%TYPE) IS

SELECT *
  FROM patient
  WHERE
    (fname = p_fname AND sname = p_sname AND dob = p_dob);


BEGIN
FOR patient IN c_patient_cursor(p_fname, p_sname, p_dob, p_gender)
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'Patient Forename: ' ||patient.fname|| CHR(10)||'Patient Surname: ' ||patient.sname|| CHR(10)||'Patient DOB: '||patient.dob);
END LOOP;

END find_patient;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the similar situation when I was working under Oracle environment. Unfortunately, I did not have to deal this issue on ASP.Net. At that shop, everything was handled on web service (someone else trouble)
Anyway, I had to deal with other tool.

I believe the following link should help you

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2222781/Returning-Rows-Through-a-Table-Function-in-Oracle.htm

See if that help. It returns the rows of records. Then you can bind the result into grid view.

First, understand that part of Oracle. See if that helps. Then you need to bind the result back to gridview

Good luck